# Passing lamda to std::find

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, find

Probably its a late night struggle, but I am stuck with a simple thing here guys:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5 };
    int N;
    std::cin>>N;
    auto it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), [=](auto it)
        {
            return it*it == N;
        });
}
```

I just want the first value whose square is N, and compiler erred with:

```
error C2678: binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Please hint what am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `find_if` instead of `find`.